# Photoshop Vibrance effect in OpenCV

Tags: android, c++, opencv, photoshop

I want to implement Photoshop Vibrance effect in OpenCV C++, can anyone tell me a mathematical formula for implementing the exact effect for a value of vibrance given by the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have a look at the following link.

http://www.photo-mark.com/notes/2009/jan/19/analyzing-photoshop-vibrance-and-saturation/

it seems for me that the vibrance effect controls the saturation channel on HSB or HSV colormodel with gamma adjustment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Helicity i already looked at the link you posted in your answer but the algorithm for vibrance is much more then gamma correction (of saturation channel) only and the problem is i need to implement the exact effect.